# Create dataframe with date ranges from Date column values

Tags: python, pandas

Given the following dataframe:

| person | 2018-01 | 2018-02 | 2018-03 | 2018-04 | 2018-05 | 2018-06 | 2018-07 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| p1 |  | y | y |  | y | y | y |
| p2 | y | y |  | y | y |  |  |

I want to return the start date and ending date of consecutive "y" days as follows:

| person | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 20180201 | 20180331 |
| p1 | 20180501 | 20180731 |
| p2 | 20180101 | 20180228 |
| p2 | 20180401 | 20180531 |

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Sorry about that, the table looked fine in preview. Thanks @Paul H

Comment: Hey, your return data is wrong in second line. end_date for p2 should be 2018-05-31 due to consecutive months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are loading the data from excel:

```
import pandas as pd

# Input data prep
data = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
data = data.T
data.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Setting the proper header
new_header = data.iloc[0]
data = data[1:]
data.columns = new_header

# Easy to work with 1 and 0 for consecutives with cumsum
data = data.fillna(0)
data = data.replace("y", 1)


df_result = pd.DataFrame() # Store your desired table

for column in data.columns[1:]: # per person iteration
    df_temp = data[["person", column]]

    df_temp['consecutive'] = (df_temp[column].diff(1) != 0).cumsum()
    df_temp = df_temp[df_temp[column] > 0]

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame({
        'person': column,
        'start_date': df_temp.groupby('consecutive')["person"].first(),
        'end_date': df_temp.groupby('consecutive')["person"].last()
    }).reset_index(drop=True)

    df_result = df_result.append(df_temp)

# First and last day of month
df_result['start_date'] = df_result['start_date'].values.astype('datetime64[M]')
df_result['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_result['end_date']) + MonthEnd(1)
print(df_result)
```